# Como pegar os dados do select(MYSQL) e exibir em campos diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia!! O B.O é o seguinte:

Tenho meu select no php onde pego os dados da tabela, queria saber como faço para que esses dados seja separados e exibidos individualmente.

Ex: `SELECT nome_cliente, idade_cliente From tb_cliente WHERE COD_cliente={$x}`

Essa consulta irá me retornar apenas uma linha, dessa forma queria pegar esses

resultados e colocar cada um em uma variavel para que possa pegar o nome e

colocar no value de um input e a idade no value de outro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo que conecte no Mysql utilizando a classe PDO, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$user = "usuario";
$pass = "senha";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $server . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT nome_cliente, idade_cliente From tb_cliente WHERE COD_cliente={$x}') as $row) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="nome" value="' . $row["nome_cliente"] . '"><br>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="nome" value="' . $row["idade_cliente"] . '"><br>';
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```